# Fourier sine series for function F(t) = t for 0<t<L

Tags: fourier-series

[image]

How to get to the part circled with red? I tried to compute it on Wolfram alpha.. 
(http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%2FL+*Integrate+x+sin%28%28n+pi+x%29%2FL%29+dx+from+0+to+L)
Still confused. Need help.

Comment: You have mistyped the parentheses at WA, and let it integrate $x\frac{\sin (n\pi x)}{L}$.

Comment: Just edited the question. I hope its correct now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all right, the only problem is that Wolfram Alpha didn't know that $n$ is an integer. For a non-integral $n$, you can't in general simplify Wolfram Alpha's result. For $n$ an integer, you can simplify

$$\sin (n\pi) = 0$$

and

$$\cos (n\pi) = (-1)^n$$

to get the simpler result.